# Is there any resources where basic authentication is used with role-based authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have ASP.NET Core Web API project with **Basic Authentication**
(copy of this project https://github.com/cornflourblue/dotnet-5-basic-authentication-api)
and I want to add **Role-Based Authorization** to this project. Most of tutorials are using JWT token authentication along with Role-based authorization and it makes hard for me to use. What should I do to add Role-based authorization in this project?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way i Think so..Better You can try with same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).